# JS Format 201708 into M yy format

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, date-format

I have a string in this format `201708` where the first four numbers are the year and the last two the month's. The result being a date of August 2017.

My first idea was to just make it to an date but won't work for me

```
var formattedDate = new Date("201708")
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Separate the date with a hyphen.

```js
let b = "201708"
let b_with_hyphen = b.substring(0, 4) + "-" + b.slice(4)
// '2017-08'

let formattedDate = new Date(b_with_hyphen)
console.log(formattedDate.toUTCString())
```

Comment: You should use code snippets to make your code runnable.

Answer (score 1):

use `substring()` to split the string into year and month, then use those when calling `Date()`.

```js
let input = '201708';
let year = parseInt(input.substring(0, 4));
let month = parseInt(input.substring(5));
let date = new Date(year, month-1);
console.log(date);
```

You have to subtract `1` from `month` because JS counts months starting from `0`.